Resilience4j circuit breaker configuration for ignoredExceptions - fault tolerant for classes not found
Currently, if there's a class that's not in the classpath in the ignoredExceptions block, the application will fail to start up.  Is there a way to make this fault tolerant and simply ignore any classes not found in the ignoredExceptions list?
The reason why I ask is because we have overhauled and repackaged our exception classes ever so slightly and makes cutover from old > new difficult given this limitation.   Below is a backward and forward compatible configuration allowing the app to be upgraded or backed out to old version having both the old and new classes defined.
resilience4j:
  circuitbreaker:
  configs:
    default:
    ignoreExceptions:
      -  com.sample.exception.Exception1
      -  com.sample.exception.Exception2
      -  com.sample.new.package.Exception1
      -  com.sample.new.package.Exception2

I tried looking at the R4j documentation and couldn't find anything that allowed this.  We have some ways we can support multiple sets of configurations with different versions also.
